# Append string using regex at the end of URL values inside the nested object on Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, object, ecmascript-6

Sample object (the below object is a very large nested object):

```
const obj = { a: 1, url: "https://someurl.com", b: { c: 1, d: { otherUrl: "https://someotherurl.com"}};
```

I want to append some query parameter at the end of each URL, like `?d=1234`.

I tried to do it, but the URLs are changed:

```
const convertedObj = JSON.stringify(obj);
let bufferObj;
const fullRegex = /url":"([^"]*)/g;
const fullMatch = convertedObj.match(fullRegex);

if(fullMatch) {
  fullMatch.forEach((str, i) => {
    bufferObj = convertedObj.replace(/(url|Url)":"([^"]*)/g, `${str}?d=1234`);
  });
}
```

Is there a solution for this in Node.js using regex?

Answer (score 0):

```
let convertedObj = JSON.stringify(obj);
const fullRegex = /(url|Url)":"([^"]*)/g;
const fullMatch = convertedObj.match(fullRegex);

if(fullMatch) {
  fullMatch.forEach((str, i) => {
    convertedObj = convertedObj.replace(str, `${str}?d=1234`);
  });
}
console.log(convertedObj);
```

Comment: Can you make it more clear it is actually an answer? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written right now.)

Comment: You can [edit (change)](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70742393/edit) your answer.